# (501) Not Implemented when trying to export a table to GC

Tags: php, csv, google-bigquery

I have this code for export a table:

```
$job = new Google_Service_Bigquery_Job();
$config = new Google_Service_Bigquery_JobConfiguration();
$config->setDryRun(true);
$extractConfig = new Google_Service_Bigquery_JobConfigurationExtract();
$sourceTable = new Google_Service_Bigquery_TableReference;

$sourceTable->setDatasetId(DATASET_ID);
$sourceTable->setProjectId('aerobic-forge-504');
$sourceTable->setTableId('carmen_table1');

$extractConfig->setSourceTable($sourceTable);
$extractConfig->setDestinationFormat('CSV');

$dataFile = "gs://{my_bucket_edited}/reports_stage1.csv";
$extractConfig->setDestinationUri($dataFile);

$config->setExtract($extractConfig);
$job->setConfiguration($config);

try {
    $job = $bq->jobs->insert(PROJECT_ID, $job);
    $status = new Google_Service_Bigquery_JobStatus();
    $status = $job->getStatus();
    if ($status->count() != 0) {
        $err_res = $status->getErrorResult();
        die($err_res->getMessage());
    }
} catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
    print_r($e->getErrors());// HERE I GET THE ERROR
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

When I run this I get this error:

> Error calling POST
>   https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/aerobic-forge-504/jobs:
>   (501) Not Implemented: Not implemented

```
 Array
        (
            [domain] => global
            [reason] => notImplemented
            [message] => Not Implemented: Not implemented
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is that you're trying to perform a `dryRun` of an extract job, which is not implemented. Try setting dryRun to false.